# Rspec failing 4 examples, 1 failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

#### **I've been following along with Michael Hartl's tutorial, although for some reason I seem to be getting this error when testing:**

```
Failures:   

1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",
   expected css "title" to return something
 # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.11535 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:16 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

Randomized with seed 19403
```

#### **Here are my pages_controller_spec file contents:**

```
require 'spec_helper'



describe PagesController do


render_views

describe "GET 'home'" do
it "returns http success" do
  get 'home'
  response.should be_success
end

it "should have the right title" do
  get 'home'
  response.should have_selector("title", 
      :content => "Ruby on rails tutorial sample app | Home")
 end
 end

describe "GET 'contact'" do
it "returns http success" do
  get 'contact'
  response.should be_success
 end
end


describe "GET 'about'" do
it "returns http success" do
  get 'about'
  response.should be_success
end
 end
 end
```

#### **And here are the contents of my home.html.erb file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ruby on rails tutorial sample app | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pages#home</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that happened to me too. Please just make sure that you are using that exact version of Capybara mentioned in the tutorial. i.e. 1.1.2

I have tried many variations and alternatives and have reached the conclusion that there is still some compatibility issues in the latest Capybara.

Hope this helps.

> Update: Nailed it. Checkout the source of the home page from your
>   browser. Since application layout uses a yield inside `<body>`, all you
>   html in home.html.erb is actually replaced inside the body(even the
>   `<title>` part is being substituted inside `<body>` tag), effectively
>   nullifying `<head>` and `<title>` elements. That's why there is no view
>   specific title yet. The title defined in
>   /views/layout/application.html.erb is being used on your home page.

My advice is to push on with the tutorial. In just a few steps, you will be pass the tests.

Comment: And I sure hope that whatever is wrong with version 2 gets sorted out soon.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just double checked and I am using Capybara 1.1.2, here is the content of my gemfile: source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

Comment: Please try replacing content with text. i.e have_selector('title', :text => "Home")

Comment: No dice, error is the following: ailures:

  1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",
       expected css "title" with text "Ruby on rails tutorial sample app | Home" to return something

Comment: try using capybara's 'visit' instead of 'get' to visit a page. After that use 'page' instead of 'response'.------------ Example: visit 'home'---------page.should have_selector...

Comment: Hm, still getting the same error: Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:16 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

Comment: are you using git? Kindly commit and send me the link. That way I can help you much better

Comment: Certainly. https://github.com/Apane/sample_app1.git -thank you.